# Phone losing signal after switching on mobile data

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cellular-data

I have been using a JIO 4G LTE Sim in my Blu WIN HD LTE for quite a while now and never had any problems. Yesterday morning I woke up and found that sim slot 1 (which had my JIO sim) had no signals. I rebooted the phone and signals came back. However, since then, within a few minutes of switching on mobile data (which uses sim 1 ofc), the sim would lose all signals. It just fails to detect any network. However, if the data is switched off, the signal remains. Since my phone doesn't support voLTE, I can't make calls from the sim. I've only been using it for mobile data.

I called up the JIO customer support and they said that my phone doesn't support the sim which makes no sense at all as I have been using this sim for the past 6 months or so without any problems whatsoever. But the customer support insists on saying that this is a handset related issue.

I am thinking to try hard resetting as a fix but would like to avoid that right away.

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried reinsertting the Sim in Sim slot to isolate the issue?